# Chargify versus Recurly

Tags: stripe-payments, recurring-billing, recurly, chargify

I'm looking for some feedback from entrepreneurs or developers that have used either Chargify or Recurly to handle their recurring billing.

More specifically, I sell a hardware device that works in unison with a companion application and charge a subscription for the functionality of the companion application. I sell both b2b and b2c. Thus, I need a recurring billing platform that can handle a single unit purchase as well as a 10-20k wholesale purchase and be able to track quantities sold. I've noticed Chargify lacks the ability for me to track quantity. Further, we have highly targeted, customized landing pages on HubSpot and would need the two platforms to integrate nicely.

Has anybody had experience with either of these platforms? What do you like and dislike about the functionality and capabilities? Which do you recommend based off what I would need it to accomplish? Alternatively, is there a different platform that you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "I've noticed Chargify lacks the ability for me to track quantity." - Chargify is able to handle this with what they call "components." Your use case is very common and definitely doable via Chargify.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. What I meant was that I didn't see the "quantity" in their webhook events. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I believe this can be done with the "component_allocation_change" event in https://docs.chargify.com/webhooks